# Add value to a URL

Tags: php, iframe, addition

How can I add a values to a link:

```
http://wl.breedbandwinkel.nl/postcodecheck/2652/BL/6?sub=alles-in-een-pakketten&domain=www.kabeladviseur.nl&aff_id=6081&focus=glasvezel&hide=mobiel-internet
```

I need to be able to add and or change the values `2652/BL/6`.

Is there any script (php) that can do that for me? So I can load the results into a new page?

This is the script that I'm running:

```
http://wl.breedbandwinkel.nl/?domain=kabeladviseur.nl&aff_id=6081&focus=glasvezel&hide=mobiel-internet
```

This is a checker that checks if the zip code is valid. I ran this within an `iframe` now, but that isn't good enough.

I hope this is clear enough for you to know what I'm looking for. If you need any more information I'm glad to give it to you.

Below is the script that I'm running for the postcode checker:

```
 <FORM name="pcc" id="pcc" method="post" action="http://wl.breedbandwinkel.nl/postcodecheck/?sub=alles-in-een-pakketten&domain=www.kabeladviseur.nl&aff_id=6081&focus=glasvezel&hide=mobiel-internet" onSubmit="return validatePcc(this);">
    <DIV class="blok">


        <H2>Ik ben op zoek naar:</H2>

        <DIV class="ff"><INPUT type="radio" class="pccrad radio" name="sub" value="alles-in-een-pakketten" id="pcc-alles-in-een-pakketten" onclick="$('#pcc-no').hide(); $('#pcc-fpcon').css('visibility', 'visible'); if($('#pcg').val() == '') $('#pcg').focus();"><LABEL class="left pcm" for="pcc-alles-in-een-pakketten" onmouseover="mpopup('Alles-in-&eacute;&eacute;n pakketten','Extra voordelig pakket met internet, digitale telefonie en/of digitale televisie.');" onmouseout="kill();">Alles-in-&eacute;&eacute;n pakketten</LABEL></DIV>         <DIV class="ff"><INPUT type="radio" class="pccrad radio" name="sub" value="internet" id="pcc-internet" onclick="$('#pcc-no').hide(); $('#pcc-fpcon').css('visibility', 'visible'); if($('#pcg').val() == '') $('#pcg').focus();"><LABEL class="left pcm" for="pcc-internet" onmouseover="mpopup('Internet','Altijd supersnel onbeperkt online tegen een vast bedrag per maand.');" onmouseout="kill();">Internet</LABEL></DIV>                      <DIV class="ff"><INPUT type="radio" class="pccrad radio" name="sub" value="digitale-televisie" id="pcc-digitale-televisie" onclick="$('#pcc-no').hide(); $('#pcc-fpcon').css('visibility', 'visible'); if($('#pcg').val() == '') $('#pcg').focus();"><LABEL class="left pcm" for="pcc-digitale-televisie" onmouseover="mpopup('Digitale Televisie','Geniet van haarscherp digitaal beeld en geluid inclusief de gratis digitale programmagids.');" onmouseout="kill();">Digitale Televisie</LABEL></DIV>    
    </DIV>

    <DIV class="blok">

        <DIV id="pcc-no" class="hide"><I>Voor het vergelijken van Mobiel Internet is geen postcode nodig.</I></DIV>

        <DIV id="pcc-fpcon">
            <H2>Mijn postcode en huisnummer zijn:</H2>

            <TABLE border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <TR>
                <TD height="14" colspan="2">Postcode</TD>
                <TD>Huisnr.</TD>
              </TR>
              <TR>
                <TD width="51"><INPUT type="text" class="text" maxlength="4" size="5" value="" name="pcg" id="pcg" onKeyUp="autoTab(event,this,4,pcl);" style="width: 41px;"></TD>
                <TD width="46"><INPUT type="text" class="text" maxlength="2" size="2" value="" name="pcl" id="pcl" onKeyUp="autoTab(event,this,2,hn);" onKeyDown="backSpace(event,this,pcg);" onBlur="upperCase(event,this);" style="width: 26px;"></TD>
                <TD width="36"><INPUT type="text" class="text" maxlength="6" size="4" value="" name="hn" id="hn" onKeyDown="backSpace(event,this,pcl);" style="width: 36px;"></TD>
              </TR>
            </TABLE>

            <U class="dot small" onmouseover="popup('Waarom mijn postcode invullen?','Om te kunnen controleren welke abonnementen op uw adres leverbaar zijn hebben wij uw postcode en huisnummer nodig.<br>Uiteraard respecteren wij uw privacy. Deze gegevens worden niet opgeslagen.');" onmouseout="kill();">Waarom mijn postcode invullen?</U>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="spa"></DIV>

        <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Vergelijk de aanbiedingen op uw adres" class="button">

    </DIV>
</FORM>
```

Comment: In general you will get this type of links if you use the $_GET method to send data to the next page. The data is added after the question mark. The stuff before is normally the URL ending with the page. If you want the postcode in front of you question mark you will probably need to do a mod_rewrite. Personally I would choose to include it after the question.

Comment: use PHP explode to explode the text then replace the values and implode them or use regex to replace and i am not good at that

Comment: Just to clarify do you want the link to the form to include the postcode? That is only possible if you provide the postcode and huisnr. first in the page linking to the form. PHP is a very nice language but I can still not guess your home address. And hat would probably also cause some serious privacy concerns. ;-) Or do you want the next page to include the postcode and huisnr. in that case you can use the same method ($_GET) as you have been using with the other variables from the form.

Comment: dont link us your frontend output. link us your code.

Comment: When you type your postcode into the form it will add the postcode to the link that I provided, as example I typed 2652/BL/6.
So yes I want to include the 2652/BL/6 into the that link. And it is before the ? mark.

Comment: Oh and now that I see. I also need to be able to change or add ?sub= that comes after the zip code. These are options that can be selected in the form as I'm showing above.